# If we know two of the polar angles and azimuth angles between three lines in space how to figure out the third one?

Tags: geometry

For example, there have three lines A, B, and C in space, each line have their own certain spherical coordinates system. We know B's and C's polar angle and azimuth angle with respect to A. How to figure out the B's polar angle and azimuth angle with respect to C (in C spherical coordinates system)?

Comment: what you mean by azimuth angle ?  is it just the angle between the lines ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The azimuth angle was measured from a fixed reference direction on a certain plane that was an orthogonal projection on a reference plane that passes through the origin and is orthogonal to the zenith.

Answer (score 0):

Does 'B's and C's polar angle and azimuth angle with respect to A' means ($\theta_B-\theta_A,~\phi_B-\phi_A$) and ($\theta_C-\theta_A,~\phi_C-\phi_A$) (btw, I mean one must define the angles in the same coordinate system). If the answer is yes, then what you want is ($\theta_B-\theta_C,~\phi_B-\phi_C$), and it should be the difference between the first two quantities.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).